# I updated to ubuntu 14.04 but now it does not show any files in home and also terminal

Tags: 14.04, updates, home-directory, shared-folders, lxterminal

I updated to ubuntu version 14.04  first it was showing blank screen but after running some codes now it opens but does not show any files in home folder
it does not even fetch terminal

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly are "some codes"? Are you at the desktop GUI? Are files missing now that used to be present in your old version of Ubuntu? What does "fetch terminal" mean?

Comment: i used apt-get update

Comment: yes the files used to be present in the older version now the screen shows a red circle on top .has error msg "ror in function update"

Comment: @ph0t0nix yeah, but that is just as bad as this one, and can't be closed as a dupe.

Comment: @Tim, indeed it's not a pure duplicate, but given that it's the same user asking the question the two problems are (very likely) related and solving one will (probably) solve the other.

Comment: @p Yes, fair point

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is a list that may fix it:

Fisrt try

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then if that doesn't work

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

If it is still broken

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

We really need more details you help you solve this.

Comment: E:didnt workthe last code says unable to locate package ubuntu

Comment: unable to locate package desktop

Comment: there is a dash between them. `ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: (y) i had missed the dash :p

Comment: it did not help :(

Comment: it has taken all the updates and is working fine  but it is not showing the file when i search for it